# How to put a value to an excel cell?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

You'll probably laugh at me, but I am sitting on this for two weeks. I'm using python with pandas.

All I want to do, is to put a calculated value in a pre-existing excel file to a specific cell without changing the rest of the file. That's it.

Openpyxl makes my file unusable (means, I can not open because it's "corrupted" or something) or it plainly delets the whole content of the file. Xlsxwriter cannot read or modify pre-existing files. So it has to be pandas.

And for some reason I can't use `worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']`, because that leads to an "unhandled exception".

Guys. Help.

Comment: Hey, can you give some details on the errors you are seeing? I'm pretty sure that Pandas is going to write to your file using `xlsxwriter` anyways, so knowing more about that issue will be helpful to know if Pandas can solve this for you.

It's probably also worth looking into why `openpyxl` isn't working. It **should** work

Comment: I might add I am working with Visual Studio 2018. Okay, the errors first: if I save the file via openpyxl, Excel says it either has the wrong format (which is not the case, it is ".xlsx") or it is destroyed. That might be a problem comming from the German money format (which has a "." as thousand separator and a "," for the decimals. I fixed that with the pandas import option). And the "unhandled exception" just says: 'Sheet1'. Nothing more.

Comment: And Pandas writes the file quite well, but I have not discovered any possibility to write a value to a specific cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a bunch of packages but (for a lot of reasons) I ended up using `xlwings`. You can do pretty much anything with it in python that you can do in Excel.

Documentation [link](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html)

So with `xlwings` you'd have:

```
import xlwings as xw
# open app_excel
app_excel = xw.App(visible = False)
# open excel template
wbk = xw.Book( r'stuff.xlsx' )
# write to a cell
wbk.sheets['Sheet1'].range('B5').value = 15

# save in the same place with the same name or not
wbk.save()
wbk.save( r'things.xlsx' )

# kill the app_excel
app_excel.kill()
del app_excel
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That does the trick, thank you! Just one more thing: now, when I open the excel file, he wants to use the document reconstruction every time. Is it because I have it opened twice from pandas and xlwings?

Comment: @Verne, no idea what's "document reconstruction" - you could share a screenshot.           But maybe you don't need to open it with pandas in the first place and you could just use xlwings? You could though read sheets into pandas and then drop them in the excel file (same place or another).

If my answer fixes your errors you could accept it as a solution

Comment: It is when Excel, or any other office app, thinks that the file you were working on crashed and offers you to reconstruct it. Oh, and thanks a lot for the solution!

Comment: @Verne, oh i see. Not sure how xlwings can help you with that.. do you get the same message when you're working only within excel with the same file? An alternative would be to Save As that file with a different name, try running your python code on it and see if you get the same message. Of course, it's not an ideal solution if you have many excel files.

Comment: Well, it is a luxurious problem, for sure, and I'm sure I will eventually get behind it. For now, this is the best outcome possible. Thanks a lot!